# Are imaginary quadratic numbers fixed by a $2 \times 2$ integral matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-forms

In Zagier's *1-2-3 of Modular Forms*, the following is written. For context, $\mathfrak{z}$ is a CM point in the upper-half plane, though this is not relevant for the question.

> By definition, $\mathfrak{z}$ satisfies a quadratic equation over $\mathbb{Z}$, say $A \mathfrak{z}^2 + B\mathfrak{z} + C = 0$. There is then always a matrix $M \in M(2,\mathbb{Z})$, not proportional to the identity, which fixes $\mathfrak{z}$. (For instance, we can take $M = \big(\begin{smallmatrix}B & C \\ -A & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\big)$.)

This seems obviously false for me. Take $\mathfrak{z}$ to be $i$. Then $i^2 + 1 = 0$, yet obviously $i$ is not a fixed point of $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \big)$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the group $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on the upper half-plane by Möbius transformations:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot z = \frac{az+b}{cz+d} \, .
$$
If $A {z}^2 + B{z} + C = 0$, then
\begin{align*}
0 = A {z}^2 + B{z} + C \iff -Az^2 = Bz+C \iff z = \frac{Bz+C}{-Az} =
\begin{pmatrix}
B & C\\
-A & 0
\end{pmatrix} \cdot z
\end{align*}
so $z$ is fixed by the given matrix as claimed. ($z \neq 0$ since it's in the upper half-plane.) For your example, we have
$$
i = -\frac{1}{i} = \frac{0 \cdot i + 1}{-1 \cdot i + 0} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \cdot i
$$
so $i$ is a fixed point of $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course! For some reason I was under the impression that the 'action' on $\mathbb{C}$ by $M(2, \mathbb{Z})$ was defined by viewing complex numbers as two-dimensional vectors and viewing the matrix as an endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^2$.